# This error is occurring when consulting the maven version

Tags: maven, installation, maven-3

This error is occurring when consulting the maven version after installation.

```
mvn -v

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getEnhancedMainMethod(Launcher.java:172)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
```

Comment: Have had installed an older version of Maven ? What version are you trying now ?

Comment: I have installed version 3.3.9.

Comment: At the time of installation I installed it with the root user, it was a permissions error. $ sudo mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_161, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-116-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention

Comment: You're welcome..

Comment: Don't install as root unless you need to.   Maven can be unpacked and added to your PATH as a normal user.